# Bourbaki Algebraic Structures Question 4.9 [maximal proper subgroups of finitely generated groups]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $\mathrm G$ be a group which does not consist only of the identity element. Suppose that there exists a finite subset $\mathrm S$ of $\mathrm G$ such that $\mathrm G$ is generated by $\mathrm S$ (resp. by the elements $\mathrm {gsg^{-1}, g \in G}$, ${s \in S}$). Let $\mathfrak R$ be the set of subgroups of G (resp. normal subgroups of G) distinct from $\mathrm G$. Show that $\mathfrak R$, ordered by inclusion, is inductive. Deduce the existence of a normal subgroup $\mathrm H$ of $\mathrm G$ such that $\mathrm {G/H}$ is simple.

Attempt: Any member of a chain of groups in $\mathfrak R$ has a maximum in $\mathfrak R$ since the union of every element in a given chain is itself in $\mathfrak R$, by Zorn's lemma $\mathfrak R$ contains at least one maximal element $\mathrm H$. In the case where $\mathfrak R$ consists of normal subgroups it is clear that $\mathrm H$ is normal in $\mathrm G$ and hence that $\mathrm{G/H}$ is simple. Less clear to me is why $\mathrm H$ in the former definition of $\mathfrak R$ is normal. The following mathoverflow discourse suggests that $\mathrm H$ itself is not necessarily normal. I am stuck.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4086/does-every-finitely-generated-group-have-a-maximal-normal-subgroup

Comment: No, a maximal subgroup does not have to be normal. But that's not what you have to show. You only need to show that there is a maximal normal subgroup and a simple quotient. Not that it arises from $\mathfrak{R}$ in both cases (which is not true).

Comment: If it doesn't arise from $\mathfrak R$ in the former case then I am most definitely stuck. No ideas.

Comment: What do you mean? It arises from the latter $\mathfrak{R}$. You've already proved it yourself. This question has two parts: the first about two versions of $\mathfrak{R}$ and the second about showing the existence of a simple quotient (which follows from the latter $\mathfrak{R}$).

Comment: Oh I think I see. I was under the impression that the structure of $\mathrm G$ in either case was distinct in general (second sentence in the question). I believe I have proven that both are equivalent ways of generating the same group, in which case the $\mathrm H$ of the theorem does the trick.